# DevExpress WPF Unbound Column with Expression Editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I'm trying to add an unbound column to my GridControl, also enabling the Expression Editor on it, so that when I open it and write a valid expression, the column value should change accordingly, but it's not working. I have a GridControl with 3 columns: Column1, Column2, and Column3. Column3 is the unbound one. The Expression Editor opens correctly, and lets me write expressions, but when I click ok on it, the value never changes, doesn't matter what I write.

I'm using DevExpress 13.1, with no possibility to upgrade. This is my code:

XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    x:Class="ExpressionEditor.MainWindow"
    Title="Expression Editor" Height="350" Width="525">

    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="myGridControl">

        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Column1" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Column2" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Column3" 
                            UnboundType="Decimal" 
                            ReadOnly="True" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView x:Name="myTableView" 
                           NavigationStyle="Cell" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>

    </dxg:GridControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the data table2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The data table2.
    /// </value>
    public ObservableCollection<CustomRow> DataTable { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataTable = new ObservableCollection<CustomRow>();
        this.myGridControl.ItemsSource = this.DataTable;

        this.Init();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void Init()
    {
        // Add Data
        this.DataTable.Add(new CustomRow { Column1 = 100, Column2 = 200 });
        this.DataTable.Add(new CustomRow { Column1 = 300, Column2 = 400 });

        // Add Unbound Column
        var column = this.myGridControl.Columns["Column3"];
        column.AllowUnboundExpressionEditor = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

CustomRow Class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom Row
/// </summary>
public class CustomRow
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the column1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The column1.
    /// </value>
    public double Column1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the column2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The column2.
    /// </value>
    public double Column2 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the column3.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The column3.
    /// </value>
    public double Column3 { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer myself. The problem is the concept of "UNBOUND Column" loses meaning if you add it to your item source (Unbound means the data isn't bound to anything). So the solution here would be to remove the "Column3" property from the CustomRow class, making the "Column3" defined on XAML a TRUE unbound column.